# For Loop not writing all instances in array

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

i am working on a program that uses a list of employees:

```
List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
   emp.Add(new Employee("Bran", 2500));
   emp.Add(new Employee("Mike", 1500));
   emp.Add(new Employee("Isaac", 1000));
   emp.Add(new Employee("Patrick", 100));
   emp.Add(new Employee("Spongebob", 2000));
   emp.Add(new Employee("Spongegar", 1200));
```

I am using linq to make a query and i want to do a sequential search so i put:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nResults of sequential search ");
Employee em = null; //flag 
string name = "Spo";
int i;

var match = from e in emp
            where e.Name.StartsWith(name)
            select e; 

em = match.FirstOrDefault();
i = emp.IndexOf(em);


MoreEmployee();
if (match.Any())
{
    for (int x =0; x < emp.Count; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((x +1) + ". " + em.Name + "    " + em.Salary.ToString("C") + "    " + em.AnnualSal.ToString("C"));
        
    }
    
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Employee Not found");
    
}
```

this output is giving me Songebob 6 times and not Songebob and Spongegar, what im i doing wrong? how do i get it to iterate through properly?

Answer (score 0):

At `em = match.FirstOrDefault();` the `em` is getting Songebob. And your for loop later on is iterating 6 times, printing it. It should be

```
if (match.Any())
{
    var x = 1;
    foreach (var empl in match)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x++ + ". " + empl.Name + "    "
            + empl.Salary.ToString("C") + "    " + empl.AnnualSal.ToString("C"));
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Employee Not found");
}
```

Comment: By the way, the way you say _"Thanks"_ on this site is up voting helpful answers and possibly eventually accepting an answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
emp.Add(new Employee("Bran", 2500));
emp.Add(new Employee("Mike", 1500));
emp.Add(new Employee("Isaac", 1000));
emp.Add(new Employee("Patrick", 100));
emp.Add(new Employee("Spongebob", 2000));
emp.Add(new Employee("Spongegar", 1200));

string name = "Spo";

var match= emp.Where(y => y.Name.StartsWith(name)).ToList();

if (match.Any())
{
     for (int x = 0; x < match.Count; x++)
     {
         Console.WriteLine((x +1) + ". " + match[x].Name + "    " + 
         match[x].Salary.ToString("C") + "    " +match[x].AnnualSal.ToString("C"));
      }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Employee Not found");
}
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

As @DotNet Developer said, your loop is iterating 6 times "on the same value" -- Spongebob.
The problem is that you are referencing the wrong count in your `For` loop. You have found the index of the correct employee "Spongebob" from your original `emp` list, but you don't reference that value again. They are also the first in the result set, but you are referencing that same employee over and over again a total of 6 times (the number of total employees in `emp`) but your result set, `em` only contains 2 employees.

Instead of using a `For` loop, either use the suggestion by @DotNet Developer and use a `Foreach` loop on the result set, `em` and refer to the count of this result set in your `For` loop -- `x < em.Count;` then access the list memebers with their list position `em[x].Name  ...`
OR
Try this instead of your code to find the match and reference the result set `em` in your `Console.Writeline` statement:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nResults of sequential search ");
string name = "Spo";
List<Employee> em = emp.Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith(name)).ToList();

for (int x = 0; x < em.Count; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine((x + 1) + ". " + em[x].Name + "    " + em[x].Salary.ToString("C") + "    " + em[x].AnnualSal.ToString("C"));
}


/* or simplify accessing the list elements by using a Foreach loop */
Console.WriteLine("or, using a Foreach loop:");

int i = 0;
foreach (var employee in em)
{
    Console.WriteLine((++i) + ". " + employee.Name + "    " + employee.Salary.ToString("C") + "    " + employee.AnnualSal.ToString("C"));
}
```